# The data is invalid. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000D) in SerialDevice.FromIdAsync(deviceId)

Tags: bluetooth, uwp, windows-10-universal

I had UWP Application running in Windows 10 Successfully but after updating to Anniversary Update of Windows 10 it won't connect.

Below methods throws

> *The data is invalid. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000D)*.

**SerialDevice.FromIdAsync(deviceId)**

Note: Previously it was working correct and i currently have one windows 10 PC without anniversary update in that application works fine.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Could you please share a demo, I can test it on my windows 10 with anniversary update.

Comment: Please refer https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/issues/484 until i come up with demo project
@ElvisXia-MSFT

Comment: Before we're going any further, could you make sure you're targeting 14393 when running on Anniversary update?

Comment: Windows 10 Anniversary Edition (10.0; Build 14393)
I have two older pc running on earlier windows 10 where i can run my app successfully....@Jackie

Comment: @user3297025, I was unable to reproduce your issue, using the same code base for USB-To-Serial converter, testing on various windows 10 releases. What devices are you using?

Comment: @jackie i was able to figured out issue by removing methods to get the devices:
await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(RfcommDeviceService.GetDeviceSelector(RfcommServiceId.SerialPort))

I am now using 
var aqs = Windows.Devices.SerialCommunication.SerialDevice.GetDeviceSelector();
            var bluetoothDevices = await Windows.Devices.Enumeration.DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(aqs, null);

but i'm pretty sure that something was updated...